# VHDL How to assign outputs from file as constants in package?

Tags: file, package, constants, vhdl, readline

I want to read from a text file big arrays of integers and assign these arrays as constants in my package. How am I going to do this? I have made a process that reads from the file and the output is the array that I want:

```
       P1: process
       file vec_file: text open read_mode is "mytext";
       variable iline: line;
       variable data_read: integer;
       variable x: integer := 0;
       begin

          while not endfile (vec_file) loop
            readline (vec_file, iline);
            read(iline,data_read);
            wait until rising_edge(clk); 
            output(x) <= data_read;
            x := x + 1;

          end loop;
          wait until rising_edge(clk); 
          wait;
      END process P1;
```

But how am I going to assign this array to my package as a constant? 
Instead of the process, should I make a function in the package body?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this simulation or synthesis code? Both is possible but synthesis code has some specialties. I would not use a process, but declare an (impure) function that reads the file and returns the value for the constant. Have a look at our on-chip RAM implementation [PoC.mem.ocrom.sp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocrom/ocrom_sp.vhdl) which uses that technique. This function is locally declared in the architecture, but can also be moved into a package.

Comment: Write a function, instead. Let it read the file content and assign its returned value to your constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of the constant array in the package through a function that reads a file, can be done as shown below:

```
package pkg is
  type output_t is array(0 to 9) of integer;  -- Just change size
  constant output : output_t;  -- Value assign is deferred
end package;

library std;
use std.textio.all;
package body pkg is

  -- Entries in output without value in file are assigned to 0
  impure function output_init return output_t is
    file vec_file: text open read_mode is "mytext";
    variable iline: line;
    variable data_read: integer;
    variable x: integer := 0;
    variable res_t : output_t := (others => 0);
  begin
    while not endfile (vec_file) loop
      readline (vec_file, iline);
      read(iline,data_read);
      res_t(x) := data_read;
      x := x + 1;
    end loop;
    return res_t;
  end function;

  constant output : output_t := output_init;

end package body;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked! But now I have to assign other constants that depend on this array. I would assign them in the package body, under the assignment of output. But then the components that use this package can't identify this constants. Where should I assign them?

Comment: Assign then after (under) the assignment of `output`, but also remember to declare them in the package, but with deferred assign, just like `output` was declared but not assigned until package body.